# Regular expression to match characters in a string, excluding matches within HTML anchor elements

Tags: c#, regex

Consider this blob of text:

```
@"
I want to match  the word 'highlight' in a string. But I don't want to match
highlight when it is contained in an HTML anchor element. The expression
should not match highlight in the following text: <a href='#'>highlight</a>
"
```

Here's what the output should look like (matches are in bold):

> I want to match  the word
>   "**highlight**" in a string. But I
>   don't want to match
>   **highlight** when it is contained in an HTML anchor element. The expression
>   should not match **highlight** in the
>   following text:
>   [highlight](http://some.where)

How would you construct an expression that matches all occurrences of **X**, excluding matches inside HTML anchor elements?

Comment: see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: ... Brilliant answer :) -- I still need a very  basic expression to handle my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you asked for RegEx, but I won't do it. Instead here's a solution using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com).

```
public static void Parse()
{
    string htmlFragment =
        @"
    I want to match  the word 'highlight' in a string. But I don't want to match
    highlight when it is contained in an HTML anchor element. The expression
    should not match highlight in the following text: <a href='#'>highlight</a> more
    ";
    HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlFragment);
    foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//.").Where(FilterTextNodes()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);
    }
}

private static Func<HtmlNode, bool> FilterTextNodes()
{
    return node => node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text && node.ParentNode != null && node.ParentNode.Name != "a" && node.OuterHtml.Contains("highlight");
}
```

Comment: I went with a JavaScript-based approach. So I'm gonna accept this answer in the name of being pragmatic :)